# Combining two SQL query commands

Tags: sql

I want to query two databases. I want all fields from db1 and one more field from db2.

The command is like this:

```
select name from db2 where id in (select id from db1 where date > '2018-1-1')
```

Then I need to query db1 for all the fields again.

```
select * from db1 date > '2018-1-1'
```

How to combine these two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This One

```
select  AA.*, BB.Name
from db1 AA
Left Join db2 BB On BB.id = AA.id
Where AA.date > '2018-1-1'
```

Comment: Thank you, Asromi.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
select db2.name, db1.*
from db1 join
     db2
     on db1.id = db2.id
where db1.date > '2018-01-01';
```

Depending on the structure of your tables this might be exactly equivalent.  However, based on your question, I'm guessing that this is what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon.